# Comparing overlap and matches in different datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics, bioinformatics, scoring-rules, overlapping-data

**My goal: a measure/test/score/etc. that can give me a numerical value for how similar two datasets are.**

Let's say I have two datasets, each with a differing number of datapoints, where each datapoint is made up of an `ID : value` pair. The IDs are the same for the two datasets, but not all IDs are present in both datasets: only some of the IDs are overlapping between the two datasets. For the overlapping IDs, the corresponding values for the two datasets can either be identical (`match`) or differ in some way (`mismatch`). For example:

```
Dataset    ID1    ID2    ID3    ID4    ID5    ID6
1          A      C      A      G      G      T
2          A      C      -      G      G      A
```

The IDs represent single nucleotide positions in various genes, and their values are variants of these particular positions. These datasets have an `overlap` of `83 % (5/6)`. Of those overlapping IDs, the `match` is `80 % (4/5)` (I only count the overlapping IDs when calculating `match`, due to laboratory/technical reasons). *I want to somehow bake these two statistical values together to form a score of some kind!*

In reality, my datasets contain several thousands of datapoints, all with the same `ID : value` structure, with identical IDs across datasets. I also don't have only two datasets, but several hundreds. The `match` is what matters in the end, but a 100% match isn't very informative/significant if it's only for 10 overlapping IDs (compare to a 99% match for 10000 IDs). For context, an `overlap` of ~10 is bad, ~50 is acceptable, ~100 is okay and ~500 or more is good (if that matters). Similarity between datasets could be thought of as representing a form of degree of biological similarity between samples, which is what I'm interested in.

Is there some good test or score system that could account for both the `match` and `overlap` statistics I'm using here?

Comment: Provide [context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl). The [bioinformatics] tag provides no more than a tantalizing hint of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Good point! I've edited the questions to hopefully provide a more clear context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think of this is as a binomial experiment. Given two samples, each base position for which the base is known for both samples is a trial; if the bases match, the trial is a success. Then you can measure the similarity between two samples using methods to estimate the parameter of a binomial distribution, particularly, the formula $(s + a)/(n + a + b)$, where $s$ is the number of successes, $n$ is the number of trials, and $a$ and $b$ are free parameters that allow you to bias the estimate in favor of a central value. In Bayesian terms, $a$ and $b$ express the prior. For example, you might choose $a = 1$ and $b = 3$ for a weak bias towards $1/4$ (I choose $1/4$ because there are 4 distinct bases in DNA). Then 5 matches on 5 positions would result in a similarity of $2/3$, whereas 20 matches on 20 positions would result in a similarity of $7/8$.

Comment: Interesting... So, it kind of doesn't take the overlap *directly* into account, but indirectly penalizes comparisons with low overlap? Is there somewhere you could point me towards where I could read more about this sort of thing? I want to understand it on a deeper level, and not just use your solution as-is. Related: say that samples with 80% match (for example) are considered to be biologically equivelant (the aim of my test), would I just use the score from your formula with the same threshold, or should I take the threshold into account in some other way?

Comment: @Sajber "Is there somewhere you could point me towards where I could read more about this sort of thing?" — Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference or a textbook on Bayesian statistics such as Kruschke's *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis*. "would I just use the score from your formula with the same threshold, or should I take the threshold into account in some other way?" — I guess you could use it unaltered.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to find the place where this equation is from, but I cannot. Is it there somewhere on that link? I was also looking at other sources from googling, but to no avail. Is this a comman equation, or is it more of something coming from your knowledge of statistics? I'm just trying to understand where it comes from and how to explain to both myself and others why I would use it.

Comment: @Sajber The formula is the posterior mean of a Bernoulli parameter that has a $\operatorname{Beta}(a, b)$ prior and for which you have observed $s$ successes in $n$ trials. I don't think you're going to understand it deeply without digging into Bayesian statistics.

Answer (score 0):

A simple metric which is (overlap/total) + (match/overlap) will be good enough. You can further add certain weights i.e m*(overlap/total) + n*(match/overlap) to favor either you want to put more importance to match or overlap.
You can even break down, and instead of putting an equal weight of m to all overlaps,assign individual weight to every overlap favoring the overlaps which you want most. The equation would look something like sum_i {m_i*overlap_i/total}, where m_i assigns individual weights to each overlap.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to take the total number of variants into account, only the overlaps, due to laboratory/technical reasons, as mentioned in my question.