# Method for evaluating categorization task

Tags: categorical-data, methodology

I have trouble picking an appropriate statistical evaluation method for my experimental data.

A number of reliable participants perform a binary categorization task over n phrases. For each data point I end up with $x$ "0" votes, and $(n-x)$ "1" votes. Now I need a measure that helps me decide when it is appropriate to assign the category "1" to a phrase, even if $x>0$.

I see several possible approaches:

- frequentist: accept the category if proportion of "1" ratings is bigger than a certain threshold (e.g. 50%)
- significance test for a single proportion: accept category "1" when its proportion is significantly higher than a certain threshold (e.g. $H_0: P(0) <= 0.5$ and $p<0.05$)
- inter-rater agreement: accept the category "1" if agreement is bigger than a certain threshold (e.g. Fleiss' cappa $\kappa>0.6$)

Unfortunately I'm fairly naive in these matters, so not sure how to choose what is best suited for the task ast hand.

//Edit -- Here are the requested details:

I'm in the planning phase of a scientific experiment. I will have participants ($n=10$ or maybe $20$) categorize phrases as either having or not having a certain property. The data table might look something like:

`id|p1|p2|...|pn
1 |0 | 1|...|1
2 |1 | 1|...|1`

with id being phrase id and pn being the participant number. I want to know when it is appropriate to assume that phrase $i$ has the property I'm looking for, when there is not full agreement between the participants. E.g. for $id=4$ I observe the following ratings: $0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1$.

Comment: If you provide [contextual information](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl), we can better guide you towards what's most appropriate for your specific case.

Comment: I've added a clarification--anything relevant missing? :)

Comment: That helps, thanks. What sort of property are you asking about? Perhaps knowing that will help me advise you regarding how much effort you should put into modeling within-subject differences.

Comment: It's a semantic property, we ask if the sentence describes a certain mental event--I expect the answers rarely to be unanimous.

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to model each case of a subject rating a phrase is as a Bernoulli trial. Then you can imagine that each distinct phrase is the Bernoulli parameter, or contributes to the Bernoulli parameter in a logistic-regression model. You can estimate the probability that the phrase is really a 1 with [the formula here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/273410), and set whatever threshold you like for a probability to be sufficiently near 0 or 1.

What this simple formula lacks is a way to account for within-subject variation, such as a subject who's heavily biased towards saying 1 for any phrase. In social science, this sort of thing is likely. If you want to account for it, you can estimate the true phrase effects with a logistic-regression model with dummy variables for the phrase and the subject; if you have lots of subjects relative to the number of phrases, it may be wise to model subjects as random intercepts rather than fixed effects. Subject characteristics, such as gender, can also be included as fixed effects.

Comment: Hmm, lets see if I get that right! If I take the phrase to be my parameter in a Baysian framework, then the mean of the posterior distribution after observing $X$ basically gives me the likelihood of observing $x_{n+1}=1$? That is, the posterior mean is my informed estimate that someone would rate phrase $\theta$ to have the property?
What I was looking for initially was the probability that phrase $\theta$ is having the property, given the data $X$. Now I'm wondering... are these two the same thing? And if yes, why?

Comment: Intuitively, I would say I'm looking for $p(\theta=1|X)$, while the probability I would calculate using the formula in the link would be $p(X|\theta)$.

Comment: To be precise, the models I described above postulate not that the phrases are really 0s or 1s, but that each has an underlying probability $θ$ of making subjects say "1"; $θ$ could have any value in $[0, 1]$, not just 0 or 1. I don't think a model that solely characterizes each item as being either a 0 or 1 will be suitable for your case, because subjects are likely to show more of a consensus on some items than others.